# how to maintain aspect ratio of browser window while resizing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some requirements, to accomplish that I need to maintain a 16:9 ratio or some dynamical aspect ratio. assume that i have a div in the browser window with some 800px * 350px dimensions by default, based on that 800*350 i will get aspect ratio that maintains.
So now my requirement is when i try to resize window i want to keep maintain that retained aspect ratio.
To avoid some weird output, when i expand width, based on the width the height should be expanded but should maintain that aspect ratio.
Ex. i have 1600*900 monitor and same 16*9 aspect ratio div contained in the browser window, when i try to resize the browser window it should maintain 16*9.
I intentionally not posting any javascript code. I just need to know correct approach.
By the way im working on a game, which runs in a canvas, its purely javascript.
Any of your suggestions will be saving my day and very helpful.

Comment: Use Viewport Height (vh) and Viewport Width (vw) or Percentage (%) instead of px. These units are based on the size of the screen and will help in maintaining the aspect ratio, This is the approach you should follow.

Comment: vh and vw, in css right ? when im resizing the browser window im able to resize the contents in the div(actual game data) according to aspect ratio(800x350) its not an issue. only when try to resize browser window, the browser window has to maintain aspect ratio. its should be in javascript. Tq for the response by the way.

Comment: Yes in CSS, I need to understand in what context the resizing of the browser window needs to work for you in order to help, As in when you press the maximize icon or stretch / pull the browser window it should maintain an aspect ratio ?